# Bind dynamically generated Grid as DataTemplate to HubSection in C#

Tags: c#, xaml

I write a small App for Win 8.1 and RT. I want to create a Hub with several sections. At designtime I don't know how many sections there will be and I don't know about their content. So I simply create an empty Hub in XAML at designtime:

```
<Hub x:Name="MainHub" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column ="1">
</Hub>
```

During runtime I create my Hubsections with their komplex Content. In XAML I would write it like this:

```
<Hub x:Name="MainHub" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column ="1">
  <HubSection>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Name="TemplateGrid">
        ...
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

I have created my TemplateGrid completly in C# and now I want to use this grid as DataTemplate of the HubSection (also created in C#) to add thie Hubsection finally to my Hub:

```
MainHub.Sections.Add(hs);
```

How can I use my TemplateGrid as DataTemplate. I cannot find any solution to it. 
So simple stuff like

```
hs.ContentTemplate = TemplateGrid as DataTemplate;
```

does not work.

Anybody an idea?

Thank you.

Cy

Answer (score 2):

move your template in Page.Resources, and set x:Key as "TemplateGrid"

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateGrid">
      <Grid>
        ...
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

in your code:

hs.ContentTemplate = this.Resources["TemplateGrid"] as DataTemplate;